# Reference property in AngularJS class (ControllerAs syntax)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lately I've been using the ControllerAs syntax, but I'm not sure how I'm able to change a model from my controller within a `$watch`.

My watch is like this:

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
    return this.allItemsSelected;
}), function (value) {
    //
})
```

In my view I got a model called `pages.selectedItems`. `pages` is the alias for my `PagesController`.

I've tried `$scope.selectedItems`, `selectedItems` andd `this.selectedItems` so far, but it won't work. Also I've wrapped it in the `angular.bind` but didn't work as well.

Anybody had this problem as well and can provide a solution?

`EDIT`

I'm using the `checklist-model` directive so the model in the ngRepeat is `checklist-model="pages.selectedItems"`. The `allItemsSelected` variable is a model from a checkbox. If its true I have to loop through my data and add the ids to the `selectedItems` array.

Comment: What type is `allItemsSelected`? if it is an object use third argument in your [watch as `true` for object equality](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), if it is an array use [`watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection)

Comment: What is `allItemsSelected` in your case? Can you show us the rest of your controller? The code you've shown us appears to be correct so the problem is surely in something you haven't shown us.

Comment: @PSL @JLRishe `allItemsSelected` is a boolean from a checkbox. If its true I have to add all the `items` in the `selectedItems` variable as array.

Comment: @guidsen So is the issue that the handler function is executing, but you're just not sure how to modify the model?

Comment: The issue is that in my view with `{{pages.selectedItems}}` I can see the array being modified, but in my controller I can't modify it for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the below which I believe should match what you're trying to do.

Note that you'll generally need to use `angular.bind()` for *both* of the functions that you pass to `$scope.$watch()`:

```js
angular.module("myModule", ['checklist-model'])
.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function MyController($scope) {
    this.options = ["hello", "goodbye", "bonsoir", "bonne nuit"];

    $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
        return this.selectAll;
    }), 
    angular.bind(this, function (value) {
        if (value) {
            this.selectedOptions = angular.copy(this.options);
        }
    }));
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/checklist-model.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="MyController as me">
  <div ng-repeat="item in me.options">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="me.selectedOptions" 
           checklist-value="item" /> {{item}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="me.selectAll" /> Select all
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="opt in me.selectedOptions">{{opt}}</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** An alternative to using `angular.bind()` is to assign `this` to a variable outside of your anonymous functions, and then use that in place of `this` within those functions:

```
angular.module("myModule", ['checklist-model'])
.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function MyController($scope) {
    var self = this;

    this.options = ["hello", "goodbye", "bonsoir", "bonne nuit"];

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return self.selectAll;
    }, function (value) {
        if (value) {
            self.selectedOptions = angular.copy(self.options);
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get rid of the `angular.bind` in the `ControllerAs` syntax?